# Serve Static File in Cucumber Test from an HTTP location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, carrierwave

I'm testing a JSON API for a model with a Carrierwave Uploader, but I'm only allowing uploads via a remote_url, so I need some way to get an HTTP address for a file in my public assets, since I know those'll always be around.

To put it another way:

When the Rails server is running, I have a static asset at `"http://localhost:3000/assets/logo.png"`. I need the address of that file while Cucumber is running - aka, I need to serve a static file while running Cucumber, so that a different part of the Rails app can "download" that file.

Edit: These test are not run with a browser, although (as of recently), they are run with a session. I may be using Cucumber, but I have written no code to use or start Capybara.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly. You may want to look into something like [Fakeweb](https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb) or [Webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) to serve back/mock external requests.

Comment: I think you nailed it.

Comment: Alas, nope, not quite, but this is probably the right tree: For one, I can't find any confirmation about how to respond to the request with a file, for another, I get the error response: `"file":["could not download file: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known","can't be blank"]`, which makes me wonder if these services are properly hijacking whatever CarrierWave uses to do the file fetch. If that's unexpected, then I need to go hack Carrierwave so it uses something that *is* hijackable by these gems.

Comment: fake edit: I just did `:body => File.open(path)`, via Fakeweb.

Comment: Upvoting so you get at least half, but I'm not yet able to confirm that these answers work.

Comment: I found the "serve a file" for Webmock, but I get the error: `"could not download file: Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET..."`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the root uri for the test server that cucumber starts by using these:

For capybara < 2.0:

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.rack_server.host
Capybara.current_session.driver.rack_server.port
```

Capybara 2.0:

```
Capybara.current_session.server.host
Capybara.current_session.server.port
```

Comment: I'm not using Capybara and this isn't for browser testing, so (as far as I know), I don't have a current_session.

Comment: Cucumber uses Capybara under the hood

Comment: Well! Awesome. I'll take a poke in Debugger and see if this works.

Comment: Stalls out on `Capybara.current_session`. Just sits there, doing nothing.